# Javascript Guess Number game with 3 difficulty levels

Tags: javascript

I coded a simple game in Javacript "Guess Number".
I think my code is good

```
var random = (Math.random());
var multiply = random * 100;
var round = Math.round(multiply) ;
var number = round;

for(var i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {

var guess = prompt( "Devine à quel nombre je pense entre 1 et 100" );

if( guess < number) { 

    alert( "Plus haut! Quel est le nombre?" );

} else if ( guess > number ) {

    alert( "Plus bas! Quel est le nombre?" );

} else {

    alert( " Bravo! Vous avez trouvé le nombre, c'était bien " + number );
}

}

alert( "GAME OVER" );
```

But, I would like to complex my game with three levels of difficulty.

Someone can help me ?

Thank you very much

```
    var level = 10 ;
    var random = (Math.random(level));
    var multiply = random * level;
    var round = Math.round(multiply) ;
    var number = round;

      for ( i=1; i<=3; i++ ) {
        var levelChoice = prompt("choisissez un niveau en tapant 1, 2 ou 3");
          if ( levelChoice = "1" ) {
            level = level
          } else if ( levelChoice = "2" ) {
            level = 100
          } else if ( levelChoice = "3" ) {
            level = 1000
          }else{
            alert( "fais d'abord un des trois niveaux, impatient!" );
          }
      }


    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {

      var guess = prompt( "Devine à quel nombre je pense entre 1 et 100" );

      if( guess < number) { 

        alert( "Plus haut! Quel est le nombre?" + (8-i) + " essais restants" );

      } else if ( guess > number ) {

        alert( "Plus bas! Quel est le nombre?" + (8-i) + " essais restants" );

      } else {

        alert( " Bravo! Vous avez trouvé le nombre, c'était bien " + number );
      }

    }
```

alert( "GAME OVER" );

Comment: So guess between 1 and (n * level_number)

Comment: I edit my message with my new code, it doesn't work but I'm lost, someone can help me?

Comment: This was for the most gibberish. Remove your answer and please try to explain what the goal of this game is and what you want us the help you with? Not just this ain't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var level = 10 ;
var random = (Math.random(level));
var multiply = random * level;
var round = Math.round(multiply) ;
var number = round;

  for ( i=1; i<=3; i++ ) {
    var levelChoice = prompt("choisissez un niveau en tapant 1, 2 ou 3");
      if ( levelChoice = "1" ) {
        level = level
      } else if ( levelChoice = "2" ) {
        level = 100
      } else if ( levelChoice = "3" ) {
        level = 1000
      }else{
        alert( "fais d'abord un des trois niveaux, impatient!" );
      }


for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {

  var guess = prompt( "Devine à quel nombre je pense entre 1 et 100" );

  if( guess < number) { 

    alert( "Plus haut! Quel est le nombre?" + (8-i) + " essais restants" );

  } else if ( guess > number ) {

    alert( "Plus bas! Quel est le nombre?" + (8-i) + " essais restants" );

  } else {

    alert( " Bravo! Vous avez trouvé le nombre, c'était bien " + number );
  }

}
}

alert( "GAME OVER" );
```

Comment: Moody - you really need to work a little harder.  People here do not like to do the work for others, they want you to show more effort, specific errors, what you have tried, specifically what aspect you are struggling with.